# Returning values from sheet in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a workbook of sheets I loop through to pull information from each table.

Due to the number of sheets I decided to store each sheet in an array, which I loop through to get the information to output in another workbook. As far as I am aware this is the fastest read/ write method in VBA.

I am looping through the Spots columns and checking if there is a value > 0.
When I `Debug.Print` the values, they return 0, when they have numbers in them (Thursday, Friday, Saturday).
[image]

What is currently being returned from the array:
[image]

Due to the length of my code, I posted my method of how I constructed the routine, with most of the code.

```vb
Sub Main()

Dim ws Worksheet

'//---Start and End Dates
    For Each ws In wbSpotPlan.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Schedule Info" Then
            'get dimensions from sheet
            lRowWS = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            lColWS = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            'set the array
            aWS = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lRowWS, lColWS).Value
            
            'loop through the rows
            For i = 1 To lRowWS
                'find the spots row for reference
                'once per sheet
                If aWS(i, 1) = "Spot Plan" Then
                    lRowSpots = i + 1
                End If
                
                'find the weeks...
                If InStr(1, aWS(i, 1), "Week") > 0 Then
                    'need to declare a date counting variable
                    Dim lWeekDayCnt As Long
                    Dim sWeekStartDate As String, dWeekStartDate As Date
                    Dim bSpotCheck As Boolean
                    Dim dStartDate As Date, dEndDate As Date
                    
                    
                    sWeekStartDate = Trim(Right(aWS(i, 1), 6))
                    dWeekStartDate = CDate(sWeekStartDate)
                    
                    'loop columns
                    'start date
                    For j = 1 To lColWS
                        If aWS(lRowSpots, j) = "Spots" Then
                            Debug.Print aWS(lRowSpots - 1, j)
                            'now quick loop to check if true
                            For k = i To (i + 5)
                                Debug.Print aWS(i, j)
                                If aWS(i, j) > 0 Then
                                    'there is a spot, therefore start date
                                    bSpotCheck = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next k
                            
                            If bSpotCheck = True Then
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                lWeekDayCnt = lWeekDayCnt + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next j
                    
                    'now calculate the start date for this week
                    dStartDate = format(dWeekStartDate + lWeekDayCnt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
.
.
.
'...continues


End Sub
```

I used the function to return the start date for the week if there are spots on that day. For example, the Monday date is the 7th, and the first day with spots is Thursday, so `dStartDate` should return 10th, but because the values in the spots are all returning `0` in the array the counter is not correct.

Comment: You should be referencing `k` here `Debug.Print aWS(i, j)`.

Comment: @SJR omg, thank you. Couldn't figure this out! Sometimes need a fresh pair of eyes. Feel free to add that as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Aye I know that feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop below wasn't referencing the variable `k` here so it was just reprinting the same array value.

```
For k = i To (i + 5)
     Debug.Print aWS(k, j)
     If aWS(k, j) > 0 Then
         'there is a spot, therefore start date
         bSpotCheck = True
         Exit For
     End If
Next k
```